# Match string with pandas series that contain a list of strings

Tags: python, pandas, split, string-matching, series

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

[image]

The values are string type. I would like to find out if each of these row contains the string `'63'`.

So I first split each the strings at `','` by doing `df['col_name'].str.split(',')`, which gives me this:

[image]

So each row now contains a list of strings. I next tried to match the string by doing `df['col_name'].str.split(',').str.contains('63')` but it gives me this:

[image]

Why? :( I'd like it to say False for all rows especially for the rows that contain the value `263`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df = pd.DataFrame({'col_name': ['196', '107,63,229', '208,263']})`

`df['col_name'].str.split(',').apply(lambda numbers: '63' in numbers)`

`=>`

`0    False
1     True
2    False
Name: col_name, dtype: bool`

Building off what you started with, how about you just use apply and check if the string `63` is in the list resulting from your call to `split`? Good luck!

Here are the [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) for apply.

Comment: Just as a general rule I wouldn't suggest using the word 'list' or any other builtins as a variable name. The `True if ... else False` construct is also unnecessary

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension.

Here is a minimal example.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [[196], [504], [63, 100], [35, 1], [63]]})

df2 = df[[63 in x for x in df['A']]]

#            A
# 2  [63, 100]
# 4       [63]
```

This works because the list comprehension produces a Boolean list. This can, of course, be assigned to a series in `df`:

```
df['Test'] = [63 in x for x in df['A']]

#            A   Test
# 0      [196]  False
# 1      [504]  False
# 2  [63, 100]   True
# 3    [35, 1]  False
# 4       [63]   True
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the easiest way to do this would be to split the column and then apply an anonymous function to check for the existence of your value.

```
df['col_name'].str.split(',').apply(lambda x: "63" in x)
```

Answering your question of why your approach doesn't work - the result of your split operation is a Series containing list values. The str accessor is obviously meant for operations on strings, so using the str on the result of your split isn't defined (would ideally be raising a TypeError)